# Calling react context prop (function) from components function

Tags: reactjs

I have a Context Consumer which works like this:

```
<ToastConsumer>
          {({ openToast }) => (
            <button onClick={() => openToast('You clicked Button A!')}>
              Button A
            </button>
          )}
        </ToastConsumer>
```

But I want to add some extra logic on the click handler and move the openToast Consumer function like this:

```
 upVote = () => {
    if (!this.state.hasVoted) {
      this.setState({
        hasVoted: true,
        rating: this.state.rating + 1,
      });

      this.vote(this.state.rating + 1);
    }

    this.openToast // not working???
  };


      <ToastConsumer>
        {({ openToast }) => (
          <div className="vote-button">
            <span
              className="vote-up vote-action cursor-pointer"
              onClick={this.upVote}
            >
               +1...
```

All of the examples provided for the Context API seem to be a simple click handler and I cant workout how to acheive a more complex example like this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`openToast` needs to be provided to `upVote` as an argument (as another answer already mentions), `upVote` becomes higher-order function:

```
upVote = openToast => () => {
  // ...
  openToast();
}
```

And used like:

```
<span onClick={this.upVote(openToast)}>
```

A way to avoid this complexity with context consumers is to make a context available in class instance. This can be done with `contextType`:

```
static contextType = ToastContext;

upVote = openToast => () => {
  // ...
  this.context.openToast();
}
```

A downside is that this restricts a component to be used with one context.

Or a context can be provided to a component with a HOC:

```
const withToast = Comp => props => (
    <ToastConsumer>
      {({ openToast }) => <Comp openToast={openToast} ...props/>}
    </ToastConsumer>
);
```

Then a component that was connected to a context with `withToast(MyComponent)` receives `openToast` as a prop:

```
upVote = openToast => () => {
  // ...
  this.props.openToast();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the very comprehensive answer

Answer (score 2):

One way to achieve this is to pass your `openToast` function into your new handler. You can do this either by wrapping the `onClick` in a function, or by currying your `upVote` function.

Examples:

Wrapping in a function:

`upVote = (openToast) => {`

`onClick={() => this.upVote(openToast)}`

Currying `upVote`:

```js
upVote = (openToast) => () => {
```

```
onClick={this.upVote(openToast)}
```